# Is it possible to prolong a button touch effect on android, even though the user no longer touches the button?

Tags: java, android, button, ontouch

I need to be able to make the app function as if a button touch lasted longer than it actually did in the real world.

For example, the user touches a button for 1 second, the app adds an X amount of predefined time on that touch, the device thinks that the user just stopped pressing the button after X amount of time has elapsed, even though the user have moved their finger before the X amount of time sets in, which sets in precisely the moment users stop touching the button.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. You would need to extend a View and override its touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Add touch listener in your view and implement your logic inside onTouch() method. Like this way:

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (event.getEventTime() > Expected time) {

                            // implement your logic here
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new 
                            AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
                            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                            alertDialog.show();
                        button.setEnabled(false);


                            return true;

                        }
                        return true;

                    }

                });
```